# XQuery 3 - get string representation of a node path

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a function that accepts a node as an argument. I would like to get the string representation of the path **whether it exists or not**.

```xml
declare function mylib:getString($node) as xs:string {
    return /*the string representation of the node's path*/
};
```

And sample invocation:

```
mylib:getString($xmlMessage/some/dummy/element);
```

Above example should return `/some/dummy/element` string. I have already tried two solutions:

1. Function path() (e.g. /some/node/path()).
2. Function [path-to-node(...)](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_path-to-node.html) within FunctX library but with no success.

Unfortunately, both functions work on existing nodes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/some/dummy/element` returns nothing, there is no way of finding out which particular nothing it returned. If the path expression selects nothing, the result is an empty sequence, and you can't apply a function to an empty sequence to determine where the empty sequence came from.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understood that last night... Besides, there was a missing variable that contains XML message in my example.